# Don't show deleted answers in the close as duplicate dialog

Tags: feature-request, bug, duplicate-questions, deleted-answers, close-dialog

Just noticed earlier that when closing as duplicate and choosing a source question, users who can see deleted posts can see deleted answers on the source question, in the dialog:

> [image]

Apart of such edge case where spam is visible out in the open (when it's hidden otherwise), I really can't see any point in including deleted answers in the close dialog. Can they please be removed?